# How to create sub dictionaries out of a large dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Python dictionary like below. In which you can see some `values` are all zeros for a given `key`. I want to create sub-dictionaries out of the main dictionary whenever it contains non-zero values.

```
74: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 75: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 76: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 77: (69, 76, 151, 157, 42),
 78: (68, 78, 150, 160, 100),
 79: (69, 77, 151, 159, 64),
 80: (69, 77, 151, 159, 64),
 81: (71, 74, 154, 158, 12),
 82: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 83: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 84: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 85: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 86: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 87: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 88: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 89: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 90: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 91: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 92: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 93: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 94: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 95: (64, 68, 150, 153, 12),
 96: (63, 79, 148, 159, 176),
 97: (64, 79, 148, 159, 165),
 98: (63, 81, 146, 175, 522),
 99: (63, 82, 145, 179, 646),
```

For example, in the above case, I should be able to create two sub-dictionaries (from 77-81 & 95-99). How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Why the numpy tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension with a condition:

```
output = {key: value for key, value in orig_dict.items() if all(value)}
```

If you want to be more explicit:

```
output = {key: value for key, value in orig_dict.items() if all(n != 0 for n in value)}
```

In both cases, `output` is

```
{77: (69, 76, 151, 157, 42),
 78: (68, 78, 150, 160, 100),
 79: (69, 77, 151, 159, 64),
 80: (69, 77, 151, 159, 64),
 81: (71, 74, 154, 158, 12),
 95: (64, 68, 150, 153, 12),
 96: (63, 79, 148, 159, 176),
 97: (64, 79, 148, 159, 165),
 98: (63, 81, 146, 175, 522),
 99: (63, 82, 145, 179, 646)}
```

The above example will add an entry to the new dictionary if and only if **all** the numbers in the tuple are non-zero. If you want to add the entry if **any** number is non-zero, change `all` to `any`.

If you want 2 (or more) dictionaries, use a loop with extra conditions:

```
a = {}
b = {}
for key, value in orig_dict.items():
    if all(value):
        if key in range(77, 82):
            a[key] = value
        elif key in range(95, 100):
            b[key] = value
```

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, then you have a bug.  You need `any()`, not `all()`.

Comment: @StuartBerg The current wording and example is a bit ambiguous, I'll add a clarification

Comment: The questioner could clarify by telling us what is supposed to happen to an entry like `(64, 68, 150, 153, 0)`, if such values are possible in their data.

Comment: Thank you!! But how can I have two sub-dictionaries? one contains the key from 77-81 and the other contains 95-99?

Comment: @ Stuart Berg such entries are not possible according to the problem definition. Thank you!